# Replace SoapUI(or any equivalent tool) with code

Tags: tools, soapui, readyapi

(Disclaimer: you can replace in this post the term SoapUI with any tool doing end-to-end testing with a UI)

My company use SoapUI to do end-to-end testing. They need to execute some tests on Selenium and other tests are REST API calls. They chose originally SoapUI to have a common tool between the teams and also because most people back in the time didn't know how to code. After some years, the SoapUI project contains mainly groovy scripts. A lot are just copied pasted from other groovy scripts.

At this point, I think the project just looks like another code project and therefore I see no good reason to continue to use SoapUI. Because we code we should use peer-review, automatic syntax linter and unit tests.

My question is: did someone bump into the same issues and how did they fix it? Is there another tool(or stack) on the market that does what SoapUI does but just by code?

Comment: you can do that without using any tool , you can use selenium and restassured together to achieve what you want. Why to create a dependency on another tool when you don't have to

Comment: Any general purpose PL has the tool-set for serving http(s) interaction. There are also numerous libraries which add some convenient features which might help you in your tests. Did you do any research on your own?

Comment: @PDHide I said tool but it could be stacks too. Thanks for sharing your stack with selenium and restassured. No need to reinvent the wheel indeed. But sometimes having a library or tool that does many things is also a good thing to simplify maintenance. And we have also competition, github and gitlab give quite the same services but by competing we will get more from both (even if it's some times debated #philosophy)

Comment: @AlexeyR. Definitely I might been stuck into a filter bubble. Library is a better word to search for tools that will do E2E testing. I already found, Puppeteer, cypress, Taiko, Cucumber.

Comment: @Ice-Blaze I am using protractor and request library ( request is deprecated use alternative ones ) to achieve it , u can find http library depending on the language binding you use.